# total numbers printing and calculating with two functions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

I'm total beginner with programming and javascript, i have coded small thing where is two inputs, user writes number on each and program plus it and gives total numbers below it

```js
function printTotal(a,b){
// this function should take values as a parameter
}

function calculateTotal(a,b){
  var c=a+b;
// this function should calculate and return
}
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Total= " +printTotal(a,b) ;
```

```html
<div class="keski"> 
  <form id="f">
     <input type=text id="n1"><br>
     <input type=text id="n2"><br>
  </form>
       <button class="g" type="button" onclick="printTotal(f.n1.value, f.n2.value)">Count</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

i have two functions which should help each other in order to make this possible( i have commented the code) , i know how to make this with one function, but dont know how to make it with two functions, do i need to put functions inside each other(nested)? sory english is not my mother language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `calculateTotal` function you need return value. In `printTotal` you can get value in 2 input and call `calculateTotal` for calculate total and print it.
Try this code:

```js
function printTotal(a, b){
  // this function should take values as a parameter

  //  print total
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Total= " + calculateTotal(a, b)
}

function calculateTotal(a,b){
  // need return total
  return Number(a) + Number(b);
// this function should calculate and return
}
```

```html
<div class="keski"> 
  <form id="f">
     <input type=text id="n1"><br>
     <input type=text id="n2"><br>
  </form>
       <button class="g" type="button" onclick="printTotal(f.n1.value, f.n2.value)">Count</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible i dont want to change anything from form just changes to javascript part

Comment: Because f.n1.value, f.n2.value is String. Your `calculateTotal` is add 2 string, 3+4 and give 34. If you want add 2 number, you can use `parseInt`, `parseFloat()`, `Number()` for change string to number and add. Example change `return a+b;` to `return Number(a) + Number(b);` in my code

Comment: Best answer, i have one question where can i read more about connecting or choosing id:s using dot like here : ’f.n2.value’ what is this called ?

Comment: I not sure. I thing it is [searching elements dom](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom#document-getelementbyid-or-just-id)

Comment: You cant find this one that list

Comment: I can read about it in [ids are global variables](http://2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html). But more a bug than this feature

Answer (score 0):

```
function printTotal(a,b) {
  return calculateTotal(a,b);
}
function calculateTotal(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this changes. Basically I moved the code that assigns value to results div, and changed a method call there.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="keski"> 
  <form id="f">
     <input type=text id="n1"><br>
     <input type=text id="n2"><br>
  </form>
       <button class="g" type="button" onclick="printTotal(f.n1.value, f.n2.value)">Count</button>
<div id="results"></div>

   </div>
 

<script>
function printTotal(a,b){
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Total= " +calculateTotal(a,b) ;
}
function calculateTotal(a,b){

var c = Number(a) + Number(b); //I use the 'Number' method here in order to avoid a and b being concatenated (treated like strings)
return c; //This return was missing so we can return value to calling method.
}
 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When i try it for example first input 3 second input 4 it gives me ’Total= undefinef’, is there something wrong with the code ? It should have given ”7”

Comment: @walee I just edited my code snippet and added some comments. You were missing a couple of steps.

Comment: i have one question where can i read more about connecting or choosing id:s using dot like here : ’f.n2.value’ what is this called ?